# Is there any way to link to a singular and specific google search result

Tags: google-search-console, google-search-api

I know how to link to a general google query results, but is there any way to link user to a singular specific google result?

For example: google search for www.website.com and show user only the top result for them to click through on

Comment: From your comment on an answer you seem to want to do this to help your SEO.  It won't help.  Sending users to a page with a single result in the hopes that they click on it won't help your site.

Answer (score 1):

> I know how to link to a general google query results

How would you do this? Bear in mind that even if you share the exact (long) URL of the SERPs, another user can still see different results depending on their location and search history.

You can share a search query, but you can't reliably share the actual search results page AFAIK - unless perhaps you also share the same *environment* somehow?

> is there any way to link user to a singular specific google result?

Glancing over the generated HTML on the Google SERPs I see no IDs or named anchors that could indicate search position enabling a specific result to be linked to.

It would be technically possible for a third party (tool) to scrape the Google SERPs and present the results in an order that could be directly referenced (this could also solve the *environment* issues as mentioned above). However, this would involve you linking to the third party, not the Google SERPs directly.

**UPDATE:** You could construct a suitably unique search query that only returns the result you are interested in, or at least returns it in the #1 spot. For example, this query return *this page*:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awebmasters.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F120837

Although I don't see how doing something like this could help SEO in any way. I suspect any linkbacks to the Goole mothership will probably just be ignored SEO-wise.

Comment: Thats what I thought. Thanks for your help. Would be great to maximize user flow through google to boost SEO

Comment: Even if you could link to a single search result, how would that "maximize user flow through google to boost SEO"? I've updated my answer with an _idea_.